# Firebase Firestore rules Issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I just changed the Cloud Firestore rule to this:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /photodata/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
       match /photodataadmin/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
        match /userdata/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have been waiting for over 20 mins to get it to propagate, but it is not working and my page has refused to fetch data.

now I get this error:

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. at new n (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:188) at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10425 at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10426 at n.onMessage (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10448) at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10365 at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10396 at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:15145 at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:15203

This is the code I use to fetch the data:

```js
  const getData = (email) => {
    db.collection("userdata")
      .doc(email)
      .get()
      .then((res) => setData(res.data()));
  };
```

Can anyone tell me what I am not doing right?

Comment: Rules propagate quite quickly, so it's likely another problem. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) that shows the [minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't do what you expect it to do against these rules.

Comment: The problem is  -
```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new n (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:188)
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10425
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10426
    at n.onMessage (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10448)
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10365
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10396
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:15145
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:15203
```

Comment: Please don't add substantial information in comments, as it becomes unreadable pretty quickly. Instead add that to the question, and add the minimal **code** that I asked for above.

Comment: I have editted my question and added more information

Comment: Please add the code you are using to fetch data

Comment: I have added it @RafaelJan

Comment: @JoeOlu So now just log in. your rules are not allowing to read or write to userdata collection if you are not logged in.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code that helps. Can you now modify the code to show that the conditions of your security rules are met, for example by logging `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` right before you call the database?

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen wrote, please log the uid to confirm you are authenticated with firebase auth. Maybe you authenticated with other system than Firebase?